# Question on Cauchy Estimates.

Tags: complex-analysis, estimation, cauchy-integral-formula

The functions $f_{k}(x) = \sin(kx)$ are infinitely differentiable on $[-1,1]$ and bounded by 1. However their derivatives at 0 are unbounded.

If we have functions $f_{k}(z) = \sin(kz)$ on the unit disc, the Cauchy Estimates provide bounds for $(\frac{\partial}{\partial z }) f_{k}(0)$. Why are these examples not contradictory?

Well I am not sure, but what I think is that the z's are complex numbers and they have an imaginary component. However, on the real numbers, we are looking at functions from two dimensions; so there is only one direction. I am not sure. Try not to work out this problem completely. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: For a fixed $k$ the derivative is obviously bounded (in terms of $k$ of course); the Cauchy estimates bound derivatives of a fixed order with the bound depending on the order, so no contradiction

Comment: Note:  $\sin(kx)$ is not bounded by $1$ for $x$ in the complex unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy estimates provide bounds for $f_k'(0)$ for each $k\in\mathbb N$. There is no contradiction between that and the assertion that the set $\{f_k'(0)\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ is unbounded.

Besides, you wrote that $f_k$ is bounded by $1$. If that means that $(\forall z\in\mathbb C):\bigl\lvert\sin(kz)\bigr\rvert\leqslant1$, then you are wrong. In fact, *no* $f_k$ is a bounded function.

Comment: I think if you're using the variable $x$, you're allowed to say they are bounded by $1$. The OP later switches to $z$, when entering the complex realm.

Comment: The OP mentions the Cauchy estimates from the start. That makes sense only in $\mathbb C$. And the truth of a mathematical statement doesn't depen upon which letter we choose.

Comment: cmonnnnnnnnnn, you definitely knew what i meant. I meant '$x$' indicates domain is $\mathbb{R}$, which means $\sin(kx)$ is bounded.